# Node.js works when run with node command but not with forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, forever

I have a Node.js app that I can run fine with this command: `node app.js`. It starts up and I can go to my server address and see it the app working. However, when I try to run the app with forever (to keep the app running on my server even when I'm not logged in), using this command: `./forever start ../../../app.js` I get the following error in the log file:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "/root/ExerciseApp/node_modules/forever/bin/views"

Here's my directory structure:

```
ExerciseApp
  /nbproject
    project.properties
    project.xml
  /public
    /css
      style.css
    /scripts
      buttons.js
  /views
    /layouts
      main.handlebars
    home.handlebars
    update.handlebars
  app.js
  .gitignore
  dbcon.js
  package.json
```

Here's the relevant parts of *app.js*:

```
//*****Express stuff*********
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

//*****BodyParser stuff*******
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//*****Handlebars stuff******
//Create instance of handlebars let it know default layout is 'main'
//Default layout is the area all the other contents will be inserted
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});
//.handlebars extensions are managed by handlebars
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
//Lets us ignore .handlebars extensions
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

var helpers = require('handlebars-helpers')();
var moment = require('moment');

//*****MySQL stuff******
var mysql = require('./dbcon.js');

app.set('port', 3645);
```

If I do the command `./forever list`, I can see that the app is running but visiting the page doesn't work.

EDIT: I'm running this on Debian Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you provide more data, and assuming the operating system is Linux and forever is installed with `npm install forever -g`, what you should do is `forever start [../path/to/filename]`, not `./forever` (which would try to run a binary called 'forever' inside the directory where you are at.

You have two choices:

a) run forever from the main directory the way I told you

b) use absolute paths in your app.js, or relative paths to ../../../../node_modules/forever

I recommend a).

Comment: This isn't a problem with the location of `forever`.  If they want to run a local `forever`, they certainly can!  The issue here has to do with an incorrect path reference in-app.

Comment: When I try to run `forever start ../../../app.js` from inside `~/ExerciseApp/node_modules/forever/bin` I get an error: `forever: command not found`

Comment: @TaylorLiss You need to install forever globally, and you need to do it as root. Try "sudo npm install forever -g". Then do "forever start app.js" from the directory app.js is in.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `dirname` so that your paths are the same regardless of how your app is run.

So you would have something like these statements

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

and

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
```

Try that and see if it works!

Comment: This could be a very lengthy rewrite in some applications and is more of a piece of duct tape on the actual issue.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn No, this is exactly the correct solution.  If your application is using data relative to it rather than the current working directory, that's how it should be referenced in code.  This is not "duct tape" it's the only correct solution.

Comment: Gave this a shot and I now get this error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/ExerciseApp/node_modules/forever/bin/views/layouts/main.handlebars'

Comment: @TaylorLiss Doubtful... you probably changed the wrong thing.  This is the right answer.

Answer (score -3):

Your working directory is all out of wack when you run forever from node_modules. Instead add a "start" script to your package.json:

```
scripts: [
  "start": "forever start app.js"
]
```

This approach uses the version of forever you have specified in package.json and doesn't require anything to be installed with -g. Also the working directory will be the same folder that has app.js and everything should work fine.

Now, any user on any system should be able to run `npm install` then `npm start` and have your app up and running in no time.

Comment: There is no need to do this.  Simply using an appropriate directory reference in-app solves the problem correctly.